# How to display an X3D object in xml/x3d on an online platform(Wix/Squarespace)?

Tags: html, xml, squarespace, 3d-modelling, x3d

I have created an X3D model which I would like to display on my blog on Wix/Squarespace. However, the sites seem to support only HTML/HTTPs which failed to display my model when I pasted my x3d code. Note that my code has no problem showing the object on any browser but it doesn't work with the code section on the sites.

I'm still new to this area, some methods may not be done quite right, please feel free to comment, and these were what I have tried:

1. Converted XML to url-encoded xml and placed it to html file
2. Used X3D validator (https://savage.nps.edu/X3dValidator), before I knew how it could help, it returned error message
   ("StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -219")

Below is the beginning of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://www.x3dom.org/release/x3dom.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.x3dom.org/release/x3dom.css"></link>
  <title>Minimalist Japanese Room</title>
</head>
<body>
```

^ the code is too long to display, not sure if I can share the entire code here. The expected result looks like the following and it should allow users to drag, zoom and rotate the object. An example is here: [X3D model online](https://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/Basic/StudentProjects/DeskIndex.html)

It now looks like this on Wix:

[image: X3D code on Wix]

Expected outcome:

[image: expected outcome]

Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: I am familiar with X3D and X3DOM, not so much with WiX. Two questions to ask of you, I'd like to help you clear this up   1: Did you fix the index problem indicated by the validator, and 2: Can you submit a bit more of your HTML markup, at least including the  <X3D ...> element, and the closing </X3D>?

Answer (score 0):

Your are retrieving the x3dom javascript library and associated css stylesheet through http: schema urls; the WiX requires https: calls. Change your script and link elements to retrieve from these URLs:

https://www.x3dom.org/release/x3dom.js
https://www.x3dom.org/release/x3dom.css